# Octave dsolve with some symbolic parameters

Tags: octave, equation, symbolic-math, differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to solve the following equation with Octave:

```
syms  y(t) k T T1 % k, T and T1 are constants.
eq1 = diff(y,t)-k*y+k*T == 0
cond=y(0)==T1
dsolve(eq1,cond)
```

but Octave runs it like this:

```
 {
(sym)

                          k⋅t
  y(t) = T + (-T + y(t))⋅ℯ   

}
```

Octave cannot solve this!!. Does anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In future, please take time to format any code in your questions.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know how to write my code like this.